# Update Processor Chain not affecting documents loaded through child entities in dataimporthandler

Tags: solr, parent-child, dataimporthandler

I am trying to load a large volume of data (>10m records), into SOLR.

I wanted to split the queries based on certain column values, and to avoid repeating the query in mutiple entities, with different where clauses. So I decided to use DIH's ability to have nested entities.

Everything works as expected except for the fact that the fields populated in child entity are not affected by the Processor Factories defined in the UpdateProcessorChain. Only those fields in the parent entity are being updated.
My data config file has,

```
    <entity name="nationalSearchResults" onError="skip"
query="select distinct zip, state, city
        from table.location 
        where  transformer="RegexTransformer">
        <field column="ZIP" name="id"/>
        <field column="STATE" name="state"/>
        <field column="CITY" name="city"/>
    <entity child="true" name="nationalSearchResultsByState" onError="skip"
    query="SELECT b.zip, c.lctn_id, c.restaurants, c.pubs, c.coffeeshops, c.cinemas
        from table.location b
        join table.business c on c.zip = b.zip"
        transformer="script:searchResultsTransformer, RegexTransformer">
        <field column="LCTN_ID" name="id"/>
        <field column="RESTAURANTS" name="restaurants"/>
        <field column="PUBS" name="pubs"/>
        <field column="COFFEESHOPS" name="coffeeshops"/>
        <field column="CINEMAS" name="cinemas"/>
        <field column="ZIP" name="zip"/>
    </entity>
</entity>
```

My Solr config file has,

```
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="updateOnCommit">
<processor class="DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>

<processor class="TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 
<processor class="RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />

<!-- To remove duplicate values in a multivalued field-->
<processor class="UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldRegex">restaurant*</str>
        <str name="fieldRegex">pub*</str>
        <str name="fieldRegex">cinema*</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" /> <!-- Necessary. Unless explicitly executing update commands in an alternative custom !UpdateRequestProcessorFactory -->
```

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    <str name="update.chain">updateOnCommit</str>
</lst>
```

Am I missing something? I can't seem to find anything specific to updateProcessorChain and child entities. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solr's URP chains currently do not affect child entities in the nested documents. See [SOLR-9477](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9477).

Feel free to add your use case to that JIRA as an example of why you need it and to also be notified when it gets fixed.

Comment: I've added the use case as a comment to the JIRA item.I'm gonna keep this question open, and close it when a resolution has been introduced.